# `gcloud compute instances create-with-container` is logging to stackdriver, but not including memory information?

Tags: gcloud, stackdriver

I'm spinning up a g1-small with the `create-with-container` command. I am able to see CPU, Network Traffic, and I/O, but not the memory. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the metrics for compute:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute

If you CTRL-F on "memory", there are 2 'types':

- `/guest/memory`
- `/instance/memory` -- these are **only** for e2 family (not g1-small)

For the `/guest/` metrics, you should follow this guidance:

https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/monitoring

And then you should be able to observe e.g. `guest/memory/bytes_used`

You can `hack` your way to a solution by ssh'ing into your VM, running `node-problem-detector` manually and then using metrics explorer with e.g. `bytes_used`:

- `gcloud compute ssh instance ...`
- `sudo systemctl start node-problem-detector`
- `sudo journalctl --unit=node-problem-detector`

And:

[image]